# How to run same function with different parameters asynchronously using asyncio in python

Tags: asynchronous, python-3.6, python-asyncio

As I'm trying to get two different outputs by running same function with different parameters asynchronously using asyncio in python.

Example:

```
import asyncio
import time


async def async_generate(sleep_time):
    s = time.perf_counter()
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    result = generate(sleep_time)
    elapsed = time.perf_counter() - s
    print(f"segment  executed in {elapsed:0.2f} seconds.")
    return result


def generate(sleep_time):
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
    return sleep_time


async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.ensure_future(async_generate(1))
    task2 = asyncio.ensure_future(async_generate(2))
    await asyncio.gather(task1,task2)
    return task1.result(), task2.result()




loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
s = time.perf_counter()
tasks = loop.run_until_complete(main())
print(tasks)
elapsed = time.perf_counter() - s
print(f"final executed in {elapsed:0.2f} seconds.")
loop.close()
```

Output:

```
segment  executed in 1.00 seconds.
segment  executed in 2.00 seconds.
(1, 2)
final executed in 3.00 seconds.
```

In above example, expecting 2 secs to complete the code execution but taking 3 secs, can you suggest me any changes ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're calling `time.sleep` which is synchronous. Instead you want to await `asyncio.sleep` (as you do in `async_generate`) and you'll need to define `generate` using `async def` so you can await it too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Actually generate function which is a time consuming function.So that I want to run it asynchronously.

Comment: Then you probably want [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html).